# Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location

Tags: android, apk, hardware, haxm, extra

my emulator stopped working and it just displayed black screen and when i tried with an external device app keeps crashing and it stops and close
and then there was a haxm installer update i tried it and this warning showed up an still it is not working

tried external device,tried installing update

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location

Comment: Could be because of [this](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/403) - recent Mac OS versions have "issues" with kernel extensions, which (*apparently*), HAXM relies on, so it cannot install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after re-installing my android studio.

1. Go to your Control panel,
2. Click on Programs and features.
3. Turn Windows features on or off.
4. Uncheck the virtual machine platform and windows hypervisor platform.
5. Restart your system

It will solve it